# CSS url path incorrect with MVC 3

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("Images/Background.jpg");
}
```

But the url it generates is incorrect no matter what variation I use.

When I run my website, the url is localhost/MYSITE as it's plonking it on a local IIS server (not iisexpress).

The image is stored in a folder called Images on the root of the application.

if I inspect the element this is what I get:

`background-image: url("Images/Background.jpg");`

gives

`url("http://localhost/MYSITE/Styles/Images/Background.jpg")`

I don't know where the Styles comes from.

`background-image: url("/Images/Background.jpg");`

gives

`url("/Images/Background.jpg")`

Which is wrong since it needs to be MYSITE/Images.

`background-image: url("~/Images/Background.jpg");`

gives

`url("http://localhost/MYSITE/Styles/~/Images/Background.jpg")`

Styles is the location of the LESS file so I guess that is sorta why?

`background-image: url("~/../Images/Background.jpg");`

gives

`url("http://localhost/MYSITE/Styles/Images/Background.jpg")`

What is going on?! Why does it keep doing these weird things?

When I deploy to live it will no longer be IP/MYSITE it will be mysite.mydomain.com so I have to get the relative pathing correct.

Comment: Resource paths tend to get tricky using MVC3 and Less.
To keep things simple, try keeping resource URL's away from includes and relative to the .less file you're using them in.
Several less implementations also seem to have problems with relative paths in includes in general. (see https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/134 ) for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give url of image in css it path start right from the folder where your css is so if your css file is inside Styles folder and you give background-image url as

```
url("/Images/Background.jpg");
```

*localhost/MYSITE/Styles/Images/Background.jpg*

because your folder structure is like this

```
Root
  Styles
  Images
```

so if you want to point some image in the `Images` folder from your css file in Styles folder you should write like this

```
url("../Images/Background.jpg");
```

It means go to the parent folder that is Root and then `Images` and then `Background.jpg`

Comment: I see, so when using url() in CSS you should avoid `"~/blahblah"` ?